# Is $H$ closed in $G$?

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, manifolds

Every smooth manifold is assumed to be Hausdorff and second-countable.

Suppose $G$ is a Lie group, $H$ is a Lie subgroup of $G$, $N$ is a closed Lie subgroup of $G$ such that $N$ is normal, $N\cap H=\{e\}$, and $NH=G$, where $NH=\{ab:a\in N, b\in H\}$.

Is $H$ closed in $G$?

[image]

Comment: Can you define "Lie subgroup"? Some authors mean by this a closed subgroup. Do you mean the image of connected Lie group by a continuous homomorphism? or something weaker without connectedness?

Comment: Hence, according to the definition, every subgroup $H$ of every Lie group $G$ is a Lie subgroup (being the image in $G$  of $H$ endowed with the discrete topology). Since your question does not refer to the additional structure on $H$, it's just the same as assuming that $H$ is an arbitrary subgroup.

Comment: In any case, take $G$ to be the 2-torus, $N$ a closed circle subgroup, $H$ a dense line. Then $NH=G$ and $H$ is not closed. This is the simplest example of a non-closed connected immersed Lie subgroup...

Comment: @YCor Every smooth manifold is assumed to be second countable.

Comment: @YCor https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3384118/can-the-closed-condition-for-h-be-removed

Comment: @Ycor I really like your example of a non-closed Lie subgroup - it is easy to visualize and insightful. However I don't believe it satisfies the condition $H \cap N = \{e\}$ from the original post. Doesn't the line intersect the circle infinitely many times?

Comment: Oh indeed, I didn't see the condition $H\cap N=\{e\}$. Indeed in this case the answer is yes.

Comment: @YCor Given the closed normal $N\subset G$, I’d say the natural generality is $H=$ arbitrary subgroup *with its induced Lie group structure* (Bourbaki Chap. III §4 nº5) (and still $NH=G$, $N\cap H=\{e\}$). In that setting I wonder if $\sigma$-compactness is even needed to exclude non-closed $H$...?

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Take in $\mathbf{R}\times\mathbf{R}$, $N=\mathbf{R}\times\{0\}$ and $H$ the graph of a non-continuous group isomorphism $\mathbf{R}\to\mathbf{R}$.

Comment: Oh! great, that completely cleans it up. And I guess (by e.g. your posted answer) we learn that such an $H$ always has discrete induced structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's true, as a general fact on topological groups.

> Let $G,H$ be $\sigma$-compact locally compact groups, $N$ a closed normal subgroup of $G$ and $i$ an injective continuous homomorphism $H\to G$. Suppose that as an abstract group one has $G=N\rtimes H$ (that is, $N\cap i(H)=\{e\}$ and $Ni(H)=G$). Then $i(H)$ is closed.

Indeed, by assumption the canonical map $N\rtimes H\to G$, $n.h\mapsto ni(h)$, is continuous and is an abstract group isomorphism. Hence, by the next lemma, it is a topological isomorphism (i.e., its inverse is continuous), and in particular $i(H)$ is closed.

**Lemma** Let $f:G\to H$ be a continuous bijective homomorphism between locally compact groups, with $G$ $\sigma$-compact. Then $f$ is a topological isomorphism, i.e., $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

For a proof of the latter (which is a simple application of Baire's theorem), see [this MathSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3335459/35400).